# Why does it say BETA?

Tags: discussion, support, beta

I wonder about the beta in the main Buddhism SE Beta header.

In particular what is the goal of the beta and what kind of feedback they are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days, a new SE site would be in "beta" when it first started.

Ideally a new site would start, become more popular and stable, and then "graduate".

"Popular" means having enough questions per day, and enough of the questions answered.

"Stable" means having enough users -- especially sufficiently "high-reputation" or regular/active users who can vote to close questions and so on, which moderators don't necessarily have time for on a busy site -- and some kind of community, i.e. regular users who will answer questions, and some established policies about what's on topic.

You can see the stats for this site here -- https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism

All our numeric stats look excellent, except "questions per day" -- we have never had enough "questions per day" to graduate -- so here we are, 5 years later, still in "beta".

Our being still in beta doesn't matter much. SE have said they won't close an otherwise healthy site for not being popular enough -- I think that "healthy" might mean essentially that it's still being moderated effectively -- so this site might be able to carry on like this indefinitely.

The benefits of graduating would be:

- Remove the "beta" label
- Possibly design a custom skin (colors and artwork) for the site, though I think that the development team hasn't had time to do that recently -- see also [Allowing CSS customization of beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254375/139866)
- Having moderator elections instead of appointed "pro tem" moderators, though I think the CMs haven't had time to do those either, recently

A while ago they graduated a bunch of beta sites, as an experiment, because those sites were more than 7 years old. This site now is 5.9 years old -- perhaps in June 2021 we could ask SE whether it would be convenient for them to let the site graduate, if the community wants it to.

Comment: So out of ~500 users visiting per day only ~3 questions? That is quite peculiar.

Comment: Stack Overflow for example has 140M views/week and 70K questions, that's a ratio of 2000 to 1 isn't it. Most of the little questions I might ask about programming are already asked and answered by other users on that site, so I too am mostly only a visitor there. Still that's part of SE's purpose -- to create a useful resource for readers, e.g. for visitors who arrive on a topic via a search engine. IMO we as users should be conscious that there are many silent guests reading over our shoulder. :-)

Comment: One thing that might get us to over 5 questions per day is a stricter multiple question policy. Nowadays people often post multiple questions in one and these are often better split imo.

Comment: I guess the problem is that these get answers before moderators can look at it so that splitting up the question would "vandalize" the answers

Comment: @116PУC Many of my questions have/had several sub-questions, I'd be a hypocrite to complain about someone else doing that. If it's a complicated problem it might take several sub-questions to explain the problem as I see it -- to ask the question -- in detail.

Comment: Also our policy is to be very lenient/permissive with questions, I don't want to complain when someone posts a question. If you like though you could comment, something like, "You might get more detailed/specific answers if you split that to ask those as several distinct questions".