# Buddhism.SE -- Potential Moderator Election -- Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

Lanka stepped down as moderator.

So now the site has two moderators -- Andrei Volkov, and ChrisW -- where it's usual to have [three](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1521/254).

Because this site is still [in Beta](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2456/254), we have never had [a moderator election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/139866) yet -- SE Community Managers suggested that we might organise a first election now, to choose that third volunteer.

Now to avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I was asked to post this to try to assess community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, if and when an actual election's nomination period starts.

There needn't be very much work to being a moderator, especially with two others helping, and this is a relatively small SE site -- see also [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)
But I think it is important to volunteer -- there were not many volunteers, when we were asked [in 2015](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1515/254), and according to [this answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2518/254) SE sites depend on whether users are willing to moderate.

**Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.**

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Comment: Very helpful & clear post re the functioning of this site, just as post is written! And, as always, Asker's ongoing very helpful, conscientious, & substantial contributions to the siteare much appreciated, as well as Asker's consistently excellent posts & contributions on the main site! Thank you :)

Comment: @MH I reposted your other comments [here as another topic](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2540/254).

Comment: just shared this link to some Temples' members. See anyone from them interested.

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised to see no nominations (including self-nominations) since 5 days from the time this was posted. In comparison, [in 2015](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1515/254), six nominations were made within 7 hours of the posting.

I would like to volunteer myself to be a moderator of Buddhism.SE, as I wish to see this site maintained and sustained. I don't have a lot of time on my hands, but with load shared between moderators, I think this should be ok.

Comment: just a friendly ping letting you know that an election is now open :)

Answer (score 1):

Since voting, democratic, isn't a tool which work in sociaties where most are not in a community mood, but consumer, lazy and inresponsible, as well as far form righteousness. And because it's a matter of gratitude and respect toward one leaving. Possible good and more useful would be if Upasaka Lanka forwards nominees of whom he thinks that they could wear his abounded shoes, possible maintain his hard gained heritage well further, make best out of the path he started to clear.

Just a suggestion, and also good to make a topic for paying honor and gratitude to him. As Buddhasasaniks might know, "one who leaves" is on of the five occasions proper for doing giving, generosity and in a community even a matter of right conduct, virtue, Sila.

Of course you can, like most chose the ways of communists and people with grave wrong views, with no regard, no gratitude, no use of veneration on proper interact, greeting but just focus on how consume without paying anything back.

As a further hint for community intetested and mods and manager:

It would be hard to gain a proper and wise moderator (or sure to get not what is useful in prosperty toward good and beyond if ignoring and follow usual ways) if :

- he doesn't feel invited by large in a community
- he isn't personal invited further by those in charge of appointing (servants of the place owner)
- he feels not to be able to carry on heritage given by ancestors
- getting freedom to act skilled (power)
- he doesn't feel that basics: generosity, respect, patient are known to the most

And to be clear in regard of Bhikkhus, monks: they are by their rules and tasks not given to do moderations:

- in not given spheres, even commercial
- for householders
- like brows the cattles of traders
- householder generally

Maybe it may help for nourish possible existing seeds here in this kolchoze.